# ASP.Net MVC 2 on nginx/mono 2.8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mono, nginx

I am trying to setup ASP.Net MVC 2 application on Linux environment. I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 on VirtualBox, then installed Mono 2.8 from sources. After that I have installed nginx and configure it as recommended [here](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx). 
Unfortunately, FastCGI shows me standard error 500 page:

```
No Application Found
Unable to find a matching application for request:
Host localhost:80
Port 80
Request Path /Default.aspx
Physical Path /var/www/mvc/Default.aspx
```

My application is located in /var/www/mvc directory. I've tried to create some stub Default.aspx file and place it in root dir of my application, but it didn't help, same error occured.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of fastcgi mono server are you using?

Comment: Any chance you actually solved this issue?  I'm currently where you were over a year ago with the error 500 page - did you manage to resolve it?  I've tried just dumping a simple index.aspx page in my site directory but I still get the error 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your application work with xsp (xsp4 if you are using .net 4.0)? You'll want to make sure that is working before you try configuring the connection to another web server.

Does nginx know where to find mono? You most likely have a parallel install and it won't be in the default paths.

I use apache, but you may still find some of the instructions on my blog useful: 
http://tqcblog.com/2010/04/02/ubuntu-subversion-teamcity-mono-2-6-and-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Yes, it works. Actually nginx doesn't need to know anything about mono, because it works with any standard FastCGI server implementation (for example with fastcgi-mono-server4). Anyway, thanks for link, maybe Apache solution will be applicable for me.

Answer (score 17):

I've been doing some testing with this as well, using all ubuntu10.10 binaries.
From what I can make from it, either nginx fails to pass the hostname of the mono server fails to receive it over the fastcgi protocol. Anyhow, the tutorial line:

```
 fastcgi-mono-server2 /applications=www.domain1.xyz:/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

doesn't work. Removing the hostname makes the thing work:

```
 fastcgi-mono-server2 /applications=/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

but this of course blocks the use of multiple virtual mono hosts.

Comment: mvc does not work with  fastcgi-mono-server2, you need  fastcgi-mono-server4

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running ASP.NET MVC 2 application you should use fastcgi-mono-server4.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you have standard MVC 2 project which doesn't have Default.aspx in root directory of your web application?

Comment: Yes, simple standard MVC 2 template app.

Comment: When you are using MVC 2 with fastcgi-mono-server2 you should include Default.aspx with it's codebehind file. However I would rather try to go with apache and mod_mono because mono fastcgi server have some performance/stability issues.

Comment: Error 500 means bad gateway. Which means either it doesn't find Default.aspx, or your virtual host. You may need to include www in front of the domain name, if you call it with www, actually you need to provide two entries, one with www, and one without. It works fine for me on mono 2.10.2.

Comment: The problem probably is: "Request Path /Default.aspx". You're using MVC, there is no Default.aspx site. Use "Request Path /" instead of "Request Path /Default.aspx"

Answer (score 3):

Adding following line in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_param resolves the issue for me. It also allows to use multiple virtual hosts.

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $host;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem just now, I too had been following the document on the mono site:

I was trying to start the fastcgi-mono-server as it suggested:

```
sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=www.domain1.xyz:/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 &
```

However when I did it like that I got the same problem as you.  I changed it to this:

```
sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 &
```

And it worked ( I had to type in www.domain1.xyz/Home/Index to see my MVC page, not worked out how to stop it looking for www.domain1.xyz/default.aspx yet XD ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the domain set in your site config matches the domain passed to the fastcgi server. So for example if your default site (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`) has the following config:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.domain1.xyz;
    ...
}
```

You would need to pass that domain into the fastcgi server:

```
sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=www.domain1.xyz:/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ ...
```

Then when you access the site it will obviously need to be with that domain you set.