# Running Mono 2.10.2.0 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: mono, nginx, debian

I have a server with:
Debian squeeze
Mono 2.10.2.0
Fastcgi-mono-server2 2.10.2.0
Nginx 1.0.8

The Nginx is configured with FastCgi according to the mono-project home page:
http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx

I have an MVC2 application in the directory /var/www/monotest

Both nginx and fastcgi-mono-server2 seems to run without errors. But I get the following error in the browser:

```
No Application Found

Unable to find a matching application for request:
Host    xx.xx.xx.xx
Port    80
Request Path    /
Physical Path   /var/www/monotest/
```

I assume that the request have been fowarded from Nginx to the fastcgi-mono-server2 and that this server can not find the application. The content of the /var/www/monotest/ is the web site that has been build from the source:

```
Content/  Global.asax  Scripts/  Views/  Web.config  bin/
```

And it works as a website when it is run on a windows machine through visual studio. It's just the standard MVC test web site.

Any strategy for debugging would be appreciated,

best regards.

Comment: Are you sure host match? this answer has a suggestion that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4651783/33236

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the domain set in your site config matches the domain passed to the fastcgi server. So for example if your default site (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`) has the following config:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.domain1.xyz;
    ...
}
```

You would need to pass that domain into the fastcgi server:

```
sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=www.domain1.xyz:/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ ...
```

Then when you access the site it will obviously need to be with that domain you set.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running some kind of quite new ASP? In that case you should run something like fastcgi-mono-server4.